# Variable value not passing in a controller using directive with ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-class

I am referencing the value of the variable in a controller in an ng-class template but its not working.

here is the html directive template URl :

```
<div class="tooltip-anchor">
<div class=" tooltip-content ehub-body" ng-class="{ 'tooltip__content--disabled': tooltipContentValue}" ng-transclude>Tooltip content</div>
</div>
```

Here is where i am using the directive in the index page

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="" ng-keyup="keyupevt()"><ehub-tooltip>Hello i am here, and i am her to stay</ehub-tooltip>over here</a>
  <a href="" ng-keyup="keyupevt()"><ehub-tooltip>Be nice to people on your way up and they will be nice to you on your way down</ehub-tooltip>click me</a>
 </div>
```

And here is the directive:
in this directive i am creating a variable and setting it to false and also trying to use it in an ng-class attribute

(function (window) {
    'use strict';

```
angular
  .module('ehub.component.tooltip', [])
    .controller('ehubTooltipCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tooltipContentValue = false;

    }])
  .directive('ehubTooltip', ehubTooltip);

function ehubTooltip() {
    var directive = {
        controller: "ehubTooltipCtrl",
        link: link,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'ehub-tooltip.html',
        restrict: 'E'

    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.keyupevt = function () {
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                $scope.tooltipContentValue = true;

            }
         }

     }
  }
```

})();

Comment: Not working in what way? What is happening, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein its is not passing it in the ng-calss but it works well in just expression {{tooltipContentValue}}
It does not show me false.. it just show the tooltipContentValue directly

Comment: Not enough known for example we can't see where `keyupevt ` is used...create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl I am using the kepup in the page where i am using the directive and that is working fine.. the function is being called when i press esc key

Comment: well without a way for us to reproduce it's very hard to help

Comment: don't drop blobs of code into comment blocks...update the question itself. Use a sandbox like plunker to create demo

Comment: @charlietfl sorry i have edited the question. thanks

Comment: Probably, you have mistake in your code `$scope.tooltipContentValue = true;`. You don't have `$scope` variable. Try `scope.tooltipContentValue = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/x4gfxc33/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('ehubTooltip', function() {
    var directive = {
      link: link,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="tooltip-anchor"><div class=" tooltip-content ehub-body" ng-class="{ \'tooltip__content--disabled\': tooltipContentValue}" ng-transclude>Tooltip content</div></div>',
      restrict: 'E'
    };
     function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.tooltipContentValue = false;
      scope.keyupevt = function() {
        if (event.keyCode === 27) {
          scope.tooltipContentValue = true;
        }
      }

    }
    return directive;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <a href="" ng-keyup="keyupevt()">
        <ehub-tooltip>Hello i am here, and i am her to stay</ehub-tooltip>over here</a>
      <a href="" ng-keyup="keyupevt()">
        <ehub-tooltip>Be nice to people on your way up and they will be nice to you on your way down</ehub-tooltip>click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```